# Lucene QueryParse discards " when parsing

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a query `-license:"CC-BY-NC" AND -license:"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)"` to be passed into  PrecedenceQueryParser.parse like this:

```
Query query = new PrecedenceQueryParser().parse(filter, '')
```

But in the generated query you can see, clauses are like `-lincense:CC-BY-NC`, "" are lost.

Is there any settings to keep the ""?

[image]

===================== UPDATE ===========================

I understand that since I'm looking for a match of CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int),
without double quotes (double quotes are just used to make it a phrase). That's why query.clauses[1].query doesn't have "" around the CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)

Now I do this:

```
    def bqb = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
    clauses.each { clause ->
        bqb.add(clause.query, clause.prohibited ? BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD : BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT)
    }

    String s = bqb.build().toString()
```

build a BooleanQuery and put clauses together,

the s then equals to `license:CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int) license:CC-BY-NC`

This is definitely not what I want, I need CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int) to be surrounded by double-quotes. Is there any way to do that?

Gibbs's could be a solution but a bit tricky I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape them.

When you pass `-license:"CC-BY-NC" AND -license:"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)"` this, use the below

```
-license:"\"CC-BY-NC\"" AND -license:"\"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)\""
```

Comment: Glad, it helped. Happy coding

Comment: Hi Gibbs, is there any documentation about this?

Comment: About this escaping part? or solr query?

Comment: escaping, I didn't see it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I will look for the reference. But solr is depending on Lucene. Lucene is written in java. In java, if you have to have quotes part of the string, you need to escape

Comment: Hi Gibbs, what I'm wondering is, fq = -license:"CC-BY-NC" AND -license:"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)" so why we don't do this -license:\"CC-BY-NC\" AND -license:\"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)\". Actually this doesn't work and yours works.

Comment: No, query term should be enclosed by `"` for multi words, if words contains `"`, then escape

Comment: Hi Gibbs, sorry I'm kind of confused. Say license is a string field and what I want to search is those exactly matching CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int), so fq=license:"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)", is it correct?

Comment: @rhbc73 - in this case, your search term is a _phrase_ consisting of a group of words, separated by spaces. To treat this as a single phrase when searching, then yes, you have to surround the phrase with double quotes. See the [terms](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Terms) documentation.

Comment: @rhbc73 comment from andrew explained very well

Comment: @andrewjames, I understand if there's space and I want it to be treated as a single phrase I have to surround it with double-quotes. so fq=license:"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)" is to find exact mathing of CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int).  But look at this -license:"\"CC-BY-NC\"" AND -license:"\"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)\"", what the un-escaped " after the lincense: means

Comment: Looking at the second term in your expression... It means you are searching for exactly the following: `"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)"`(including those two double-quotes). It is exactly this phrase because (a) there are spaces in the phrase, and (b) the phrase contains escaped double-quotes, and (c) the entire phrase is enclosed in _unescaped_ double-quotes. It is those 2 unescaped double-quotes which are acting as phrase delimiters - i.e. everything _inside_ those 2 unescaped double quotes is your phrase.

Comment: For your _first_ section `-license:"\"CC-BY-NC\""` - I have not tested it, but I think it would be the same as this: `-license:\"CC-BY-NC\"`. In other words, because there are no spaces, the two enclosing _unescaped_ double-quotes are superfluous - it's a phrase with no spaces in it.

Comment: Hi andrewjames, my fq = -license:"CC-BY-NC" AND -license:"CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int)", ingore first part, I'm looking for exact matching of CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int), because it has space so I have to surround it with double quotes. I see, that's why the parsed query clauses[1].query doesn't have double quotes around CC-BY-ND 4.0 (Int), because I'm searching something without double quotes

Comment: @rhbc73 Yes - that sounds right.But in your original question you mentioned you wanted to keep the double-quotes. I'm not sure if you still have a problem or not...

Comment: Thanks, @andrewjames no question on this but still another issue. I'll update my question soon.

Comment: Hi guys, I've decided to use @Gibbs's solution. As long as we find surrounding "" after : means we want to keep it after parsing so we'll escape them.

Answer (score 5):

Some additional information, to add to the answer provided by @gibbs:

When using the [classic query parser syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description) (which is what is being used in the question), then the following characters all have special meanings and therefore may need to be escaped, in any of the search terms where they appear:

```
+  -  &&  ||  !  (  )  {  }  [  ]  ^  "  ~  *  ?  :  \  /
```

Note that in 2 cases, these are groups of characters: `&&` and `||`.

This list is documented [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters).

The easiest way to handle all these characters is to pass each search term to the [classic `QueryParser`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.html), before building the search expression:

```
org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
```

For example:

```
String escapedSearchTerm = QueryParser.escape(searchTerm)
```