# Lucene escape character

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to escape the following lucene text, in order to search for the whole pattern and have the line number as `any` number:

`@mt:*exception* and not ExceptionDetail.Message: "Could not convert string to integer: active. Path 'NewStatus', line 120`

I use the following search, but it seems not working:

`@mt:*exception* and not ExceptionDetail.Message: Could not convert string to integer\: active. Path \'NewStatus\', line *`

any clue?
thank you.

Comment: Seems that you're missing  the `"`  before `Could not..` in your search

Comment: no, it's not working either.

Comment: In case it helps (I use Lucene, but not so much Elasticsearch), take a look at the _Escaping Special Characters_ section of [this page](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63285077/12567365). Your string looks like it contains these characters which need to be escaped: `"`, `:`, and some of the `*`s. But `'` does not need to be escaped. Like I say this is Lucene - not sure if ES is different.